# ola hallengren on Azure SQL

Tags: azure, ola-hallengren

I'm new to the use of the Ola Hallengren optimize index scripts on Azure SQL, but with out of the box settings I notice that some indices with 80-90% defrag %  en  > 80.000 page counts are simply not tackled. When I perform a manual rebuild on such an index, then everything works as it should.
Caný find any sort of threshold on this behavior.
The only peculiararity is , that these indices are non-unique, non-clustered ones involving at least 2 fields where one of the field only has empty strings . Could this be the reason?

In other words , is there a reason why the optimize script would skip rebuilding such an index?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

there are two options that filter the indexes to be rebuilt/reorganized.

> **MinNumberOfPages** Set a size, in pages; indexes with fewer number of pages are skipped for index maintenance. The default is 1000 pages.
> This is based on Microsoft’s recommendation.
>
> IndexOptimize checks page_count in sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats to
> determine the size of the index.

and

> **MaxNumberOfPages** Set a size, in pages; indexes with greater number of pages are skipped for index maintenance. The default is no
> limitation.
>
> IndexOptimize checks page_count in sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats to
> determine the size of the index.

Said that, your index is quite big and probably you did not set MaxNumberOfPages.

try to see the message output (using @Execute = 'N' and @Indexes = 'Db1.Schema1.Tbl1.Idx1' with the index you want to defrag)

It should give you the index status and action choosed.
Compare the output with what is coming out from `select * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` for the same index.

Are you using the last version of the Ola scripts? Try downloading the last version.

Comment: I do not want to skip indexes that are too large, so not setting the max number of pages would be the proper way to run the optimize I guess.  I am using the last version of the Ola scripts.  I will try and use the suggestion you made about using the @Execute = 'N' option